# Infinite Loop in Python randomly exiting

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, infinite-loop

So I'm constructing some form of a simulator but am experiencing my loop breaking for no reason.

I believe I am on Python 3.8.5 and am using Jupyter notebook. Below is an example of the code causing the problem. I kinda just wanted it to be a user-controlled simulator that goes on until the user is done with it. Currently, it works as expected but randomly shuts down (Kernal still running it seems). I unable to identify what is the exact cause, it could work for example by type inputs 1 2 2 1 3 2 <- then it just randomly stops.  I realized spamming invalid inputs causes it to randomly exit as well. Not sure what other debugging techniques I could make use of here. :(

'-1' input works normally and would stop the loop as intended.

I initially ignored it making it such that the code is continuable by just interrupting and rerunning it, but have decided to try to find out what is causing it.

I'm not sure if I have made any stupid mistake or have the logic wrong, any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
# Run simulation, when ended, simulation will continue from last run.
response = ""
main_input = ""
sec_input = ""

while True:
    print("=== Welcome to my Simulator ===")
    print("Current simulation date is ", simulation_date)
    print('''
1) Predict today's prices
2) Go to next day
3) Fast forward X days
4) Jump to X date
-1) End simulation
''')
    print(response)
    main_input = input("What would you like to do? ")
    
    if main_input == '1':
        response = "Today's prediction is ~"
        
    elif main_input == '2':
        response = "Going to next day..."
        
    elif main_input == '3':
        response = "Fast forwarding..."
        
    elif main_input == '4':
        response = "Jumping to X date"
        
    elif main_input == '-1':
        print("Simulation paused, hope you see you back soon! uWu")
        break;
    else:
        response = "Invalid Option"
    clear_output(True)
```

Edit*
Example of how it looks when it just randomly exits
[image: Random Exit Example]

Comment: Do you get an error/traceback when the loop exits unexpectedly?

Comment: @IainShelvington Nope it seems to just exit with no errors.

Comment: what does `clear_output()` do? how is it defined

Comment: Does the program show same behavior when run via Python directly?

Comment: @Matiiss Erm erm its kinda just clears the output window, I'm using the function from IPython.display. Could that be what's causing the issue? I added it to make the interface slightly less cleaner

Comment: I have no idea what impact this has but why do You have a semicolon here: `break;` and what happens if You remove it

Comment: @lllrnr101 Is there a way to run a specific cell from a notebook in command? Ahh but for this cell it doesn't require any of my other cells, hold on, I'll try copy pasting and run it through Python directly. PS the semicolon shouldn't be there, i usually write in C so its muscle reflex haha

Comment: also it could be the issue with `clear_output()` but is the problem persistent in that always if You type numbers in that particular order it will crash? because I have no issues when typing that order, it doesn't exit and btw I am not using the `clear_output`

Comment: Your jupyter logs should show you what is happening. Python does not repro the problem for me either.

Comment: @Matiss ahh it seems you're right, i had to remove clear_output() to run it through python directly, and it had no issues, removing it back in juypter fixes it as well, is there a proper way to clear the output screen you can suggest? The output screen gets quite flooded after a few instances.

Comment: @KerubinGemaYuen I heard that it is possible to use `clear_output(wait=True)` maybe that helps but if You are on windows and run the code in cmd You can use `os.system('cls')` each loop (at the start) first though You have to `import os`

Comment: Ahh, im a dumbass. I was kinda using clear_output wrongly, changing wait=False fixes it. It crashes as there was no new output to replace it, wait=False ignores that. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html

clear_output's parameter wait = True waits to clear the output until a new output is available to replace it. This was causing the code to crash unexpectedly, switching to clear_output(False) seems to fix this issue.